# Export charts to picture files

Tags: charts, spss

I need to create EPS (or TIFF) files for charts created using GPL, in order to submit for publication. There are quite a number so I want to do this from within the syntax, not manually. Any suggestions how I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following syntax will send each of the charts in your output to a separate .tiff file:

```
OUTPUT EXPORT
  /CONTENTS  EXPORT=ALL  MODELVIEWS=PRINTSETTING
  /TIF  IMAGEROOT='yourpath\yourname.tiff'
     PERCENTSIZE=100.
```

In the output window you can explore the FILE --> EXPORT menu for more exact options.

Comment: Many thanks. Tried to generate this through menus yesterday but wasn't working - worked today.

Comment: One point to note is that this produces one TIFF for each chart generated up to that point, using the 'root' file name (e.g. FigureA.tiff, FigureA1.tiff, FigureA2.tiff etc.). If you want to control the TIFF file names, need to start a new output before creating each chart.

Comment: that's right - and it can be done easily from the syntax using `output close` and `output new` and other output commands.